# Select all marked search results in Geany

Tags: editor, geany

I want to select all occurrences of a search term in a text document to copy and paste them into another file.

For example:

```
abcd"efgh.dat"ijkl
mnop"qrst.dat"uvwx
```

When seaching for `"[^"]*.dat"` with checkbox `Use regular expressions` enabled, I am ably to successfully mark the desired results `"efgh.dat"` and `"qrst.dat"` with the `Mark` button under `Find All`. But they're not selected, so I can't copy them.

How can I select all marked search result?

Comment: Please submit a feature requests. As by now the search is not intended to mark for copy.

Comment: This has been requested in 2011 and remains open https://sourceforge.net/p/geany/feature-requests/553/

Answer (score 1):

In Geany 1.36, when you select "find all" in find, the results appear in a window at the bottom called "messages".
If you select one of the results in this window and right click, a pop up allows you a choice (among others) to "copy all".
You can then paste the results where needed,
Also, with Geany's CTRL-ALT select, you can block select the prefix file info and line numbers to delete it, leaving the search lines results.

Comment: Can you give some more info on the CTRL-ALT select? How do you take the output from 'Copy All' and turn it in to what you wanted?

Comment: It seems to be CTRL+Shift on some machines. However, it's less than perfect. If you have something on line 100, then what you're selecting needs to be one space wider than anything on a line between 10 and 99.

Comment: Does not work for selections where each match is more than one line.